# Error in handling audio file in Android while using media player class

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player

Here is my code:

```
private void scanningSoundStart() {
    scanningMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scanning);
    scanningMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        }
    });
    scanningMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp,int width, int height) {
        }
    });
    scanningMediaPlayer.start();
}

private void scanningSoundStop() {
    if (scanningMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        scanningMediaPlayer.stop();
        //scanningMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to play an mp3 file from my raw folder.
The first function which is used for playing the audio file.
And the second function is used for stopping the playing audio.

I get the following error when I repeatedly playing or stopping the audio.

Error : MediaPlayer(10576): error (-19, 0)

I know that my entire approach of handling mediaplayer is wrong.

Please help me to correct this error.
And if possible suggest me how to handle mediaplayer class efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to play audio file.

```
     public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
//set up MediaPlayer    
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName) Not this i want the audio from raw folder

Comment: ok .then try this.   MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
      mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.filename);
        mPlayer2.start();

Comment: Each time i want to paly and stop the audio.

Comment: So i need something like this..audioInit(); For first time initialization and two more functions audioStart() and audioStop()...

Comment: you can stop the video just by using mplayer2.stop();

Comment: refer this tutorial for more detail   http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/59.html